# Does this system have a nontrivial periodic orbit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the following system: $$\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x'=\alpha \left( x-\dfrac{1}{3}x^3-y \right) \\ \\ y'= \dfrac{1}{\alpha} x
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$ where $\alpha \ne 0$

My first idea was to transform the system into a polar coordinate and attempted to find a positive invariant region and use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, and hence  I tried to consider $$\begin{align}
x^2+y^2=r
\end{align}$$ so I can have $$\begin{align}
x \cdot x'+y \cdot y'=r \cdot r'
\end{align}$$ and I plug in $x'$ and $y'$ . The result is pretty messy, I really can't tell when $r'>0$ and $r'<0$

I also tried $$\begin{align}
x= \sqrt{ \alpha }  r \cos \theta  \\ y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \alpha }} r \sin \theta
\end{align}$$ Then I can have $$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\alpha}x^2+\alpha y^2=r^2 \\ 
\end{align}$$ Then take the derivative with respect to $t$ to both side. However, I still can't tell when $r'>0$ and $r'<0$ after this attempt.
Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the van der Pol oscillator has a periodic orbit. There is no easy way to prove it. For small $α$ using polar coordinates and averaging gives a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the derivative of the first equation, insert the second equation to get
$$
x''+α(x^2-1)x'+x=0
$$
which is the van der Pol oscillator. It is well-known that it has a limit cycle, but Lyapunov functions are hard to find. One can explore the vector field in the regions that are obtained by subdividing the $x$-axis at the points $(-1,0,1)$ and the $y$ axis at the local extrema of the cubic that is the null-cline of the first equation. The limit cycle is close to the circle of radius 2 for small $α$ and to the hysteresis curve of the cubic for large $α$.